# Calculating the angle and converting it to degrees

Tags: c#, math, angle

I am having trouble getting an accurate angle measurement and converting it to degrees.

I first calculated the distance with:

```
double distance = Math.Sqrt(deltax + deltay);
Console.WriteLine("Distance :" + Math.Round(distance, 3));
Console.WriteLine("");
```

Then *tried* to calculate the angle:

```
double angle = Math.Atan2(deltay, deltax);
double RadiantoDegree = (angle * 180 / Math.PI);
Math.Round((decimal)angle, 3);
Console.WriteLine("Angle :" + angle)
```

With inputs such as x1=2, y1=2, x2=1, y2=1, the angle should measure -135.000 degrees.

Comment: What were the inputs, and what output did you get, and what output were you expecting?

Comment: Your conversion from `double` to `decimal` could introduce precision and rounding variances in the output. Is your calculation off by a small amount, or is it completely wrong?

Comment: With inputs such as 1x=2, 1y=2, 2x=1, 2y=1, the angle should measure -135.000 degrees. However I got 0.785 degrees.

Comment: Okay now your input is confusing me. Are these two different input sets?

Comment: What are the values that are going into `deltay` and `deltax`?

Comment: Are you still having a problem or did you get it resolved? If the answer below solved the issue for you, could you accept it as the answer so that the question is marked as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using your converted value of `angle`.

You could do:

```
angle = (angle * 180 / Math.PI);
```

instead of defining `RadiantToDegree` but never using it. So what happens is right now you are basically just printing your angle in radians.